# GAE NDB PickleProperty for dict: new entity taking old property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, pickle, app-engine-ndb

Looks like a bug to me, but maybe someone will have a reasonable explanation for this.
Consider the following code:

```
class Test(ndb.Model):
    a= ndb.IntegerProperty()
    p = ndb.PickleProperty(default={})
```

Now do the following:

```
>> t1 = Test()
>> t1.p['a'] = 1
>> t1.p['b'] = 2
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Up to here, all is fine.  But now:

```
>> t2 = Test()
>> t2.p
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

The brand new t2 instance has been assigned the p value from t1 ?!!

Any explanation for this other than a bug ? 
Note that doing a put() of t1 does not change the behaviour.

Comment: @Alex Martelli The DictPickleProperty seemed like the perfect solution, but it turns out properties' `__init__` methods are not called when creating a new entity of the containing ndb Model class.   In other words, I change p into a `DictPickleProperty()` in the question's sample, then I instanciate `t1= Test()` But  `DictPickleProperty`'s init is not called.  Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, default arguments are evaluated **once** -- so you're using a **single** `dict` (your `default={}` is a single dict per process, not one per entity!) across all entities of kind `Test`, which happen to be within the same process, and for which `p` is not explicitly set.

If you do `t=Test(p={})` then `t` will be fine, with its own `dict`.  If you do `t=Test()` and then `t.p = {}` you'll also be fine.  But if you don't set the entity's specific `p` one way or another, it will be using the same default `dict` that happens to be the one used by all entities of that kind, within the same process, which don't have `p` set explicitly.

When you `put` a `Test` entity, what goes to the datastore is a pickled "snapshot" of its `p` at that time -- when you `get` it back, it will be restored to that state, and now disconnected from other possible uses of the `default` single-`dict`-per-process.  But these are just more anomalies in that dubious usage.

Briefly put, **mutable default values** are not a good idea in Python -- people hardly ever use them correctly.  And that applies to calls to `ndb.PickleProperty` at least as much as to any other call to other Python callables!

Added: if you need a `PickleProperty` to hold specifically a dict, and find it too cumbersome to explicitly add `p={}` each time you instantiate that kind of entity, subclassing `PickleProperty` may help.  I.e:

```
class DictPickleProperty(ndb.PickleProperty):
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        kwds['default'] = kwds.get('default', {})
        super(DictPickleProperty, self).__init__(**kwds)
```

What you want to do if `default` is (A) not specified, or (B) specified as something that's not a `dict`, is of course up to you.  This simple example does nothing special in case (B) -- (so e.g `default=[]` would still cause problems) -- but does use a new empy `dict` in case (A).

Alternatively, you might try to transform any provided `default` value into a new `dict` (so a `[]` or `{}` would make a new empty `dict`, but many other values would raise an exception):

```
        kwds['default'] = dict(kwds.get('default', ()))
```

or, of course, many other variants yet.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, it's open source so easily examined.  In ext/ndb/model.py, class `Property`, I see nothing fancy, just `if default is not None: self._default = default` at line 880.  Let me research bad old `db`, it's been so many years since I last used it...

Comment: OK, great, thanks !   Not a bug then, but still not quite what one would expect and want !   Doing an __init__() could have been an alternative ?   But __init__ with Ndb instances is called upon reading, so it could overwrite properties that have been read ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, checked `db` -- no tricks at all there either (for their only property that might have a mutable underlying type, `ListProperty`).

Comment: @patb, I know, people keep complaining about this specific aspect of Python -- this is no place for debate, but it so happens that I fiercely disagree with those complaints -- been fighting about that for over 15 years now.  A `PickleProperty` subclass is what you may want in this case, let me edit the A to show how -- the model's `__init__` is irrelevant, it's the **property**'s `__init__` that you want to slightly tweak.

Comment: @patb, so is there some reason you're not accepting this answer (clicking on the checkmark outline to the left of the answer)?  What is it missing?  If you let me know I can see what I can do about it!

Comment: Sorry, great answer.  It's my first question here...  don't know the etiquette !

Comment: I don't really see how the property wrapper does anything different.. if you hand it a default = [], thus giving it to its super constructor, are you not giving the default value to the class as a whole instead of the individual instance?

Comment: @bgenchei, see case (A) in my "Added" part -- that's for when you **don't** explicitly express the `default=`.